# What it means "Decisions in 10 minutes or less, or the next one is free."?

Tags: jokes

What does this quote means "Decisions in 10 minutes or less, or the next one is free."?

From: http://news.microsoft.com/2000/02/16/the-motivator-behind-the-windows-2000-development-team/

The **next decision** is free?
Which doesn't make a lot of sense and that's exactly the point of the (silly) joke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a reference to, "or the next one is free," which is a common advertising phrase.

[e.g. Guaranteed 29-minute oil change or the next one is free!](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1144&dat=19900726&id=64McAAAAIBAJ&sjid=qWMEAAAAIBAJ&pg=1671,4282729&hl=en) (from 1990, seems to be one of the oldest examples)

[or Dairy Queen's "Get your BLIZZARD treat served upside down or your next one’s free"](https://www.facebook.com/dairyqueen/videos/10153291952766669/) (from late 2015)

Comment: [Newspaper from 1988](https://www.newspapers.com/newspage/112442220/) -- I guessed pizzas would have been one of the first uses, but your search was quicker than mine! However, a useful addition to your answer would be to mention that the time limit is important: decisions need to be made in ten minutes in order to progress the project.

Comment: Yes, I understand he's referring to that advertising phrase. But what "next" is free? The decision? Or it just doesn't matter. And is it supposed to be a joke? Is it just me that thinks it's just mildly funny? (I know sense of humor and English are two different things, but bear with me please :) )

Comment: Not sure if this really answered it. I believe it to be the idea the next decision will be made for you, without your input, as any decision is better than no decision at all.